# Can't create a comment in Capybara/Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I have the following feature:

```
Scenario: when delete a post
  Given I created a post with the title "Test", author "Testauthor" and body "Testbody"
  When I browse "/posts" and click on "Destroy"
  Then I should see the text "Comment was successfully destroyed."
```

The problematic code is this Given imeplementation:

```
Given(/^I created a post with a comment with title "([^"]*)", author "([^"]*)" and body "([^"]*)"$/) do |title, author, body|
  post = Post.create! title: 'Test', author: 'Test', body: 'Test', published_at: DateTime.now
  Comment.create! title: title, author: author, body: body, published_at: DateTime.now, post_id: post.id
end
```

For some reason `expect(Comment.count).to eq(1)` is false and there are no Comments. What am I doing wrong?

**added repository:** https://github.com/cwansart/SQ-Hausarbeit/tree/cucumber/features It's the posts_show.feature and the posts_show_steps.rb.

Comment: Are you sure the comment is being created correctly? We still need to see some more of your code, especially around comment creation.

Comment: Yes, I know am. Here's the full code: https://github.com/cwansart/SQ-Hausarbeit/tree/cucumber/features It's the posts_show.feature and the posts_show_steps.rb.

Comment: I don't see `expect(Comment.count).to eq(1)` anywhere in your repo??  What failure exactly are you having?

Comment: That was just a test. In the end I want to make a click, but there is no Destroy link, that's why i checked Comment.count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned your repo and took a look.

```
  Scenario: when delete a post
    Given I created a post with the title "Test", author "Testauthor" and body "Testbody"
    When I browse "/posts" and click on "Destroy"
    Then I should see the text "Comment was successfully destroyed."
```

posts_show_steps.rb:

```
Given(/^I created a post with a comment with title "([^"]*)", author "([^"]*)" and body "([^"]*)"$/) do |title, author, body|
  post = Post.create! title: 'Test', author: 'Test', body: 'Test', published_at: DateTime.now
  Comment.create! title: title, author: author, body: body, published_at: DateTime.now, post_id: post.id

  print "#########################"
  print Comment.all.pretty_print_inspect
  ## this shows the comment. It **does** exist...
end

When(/^I browse "([^"]*)" and click on "([^"]*)"$/) do |url, click_text|
  print "#########################"
  print Comment.all.pretty_print_inspect
  ## here it doesn't exist any longer...

  visit url
end
```

Here, you create a post *without a comment*, that's the first problem i.e. there isn't a comment to delete! This can be fixed by changing this `Given` to:

```
Given I created a post with a comment with title "CommTitle", author "CommAuthor" and body "CommBody"
```

(may as well reuse that step definition, but this would be better if this test just created a post with no Comment, strictly-speaking.)

You also need to actually click on the Destroy link in your step definition - add `click_on click_text` after `visit url` in your step definition.

You also need to change "Comment was successfully destroyed." to "Post was successfully destroyed." in your `posts_show_feature.rb` spec, because that is what you're testing now.

That test will now pass.

However, you want to test that a `Post`'s `Comment`s are destroyed when that `Post` is destroyed, yes?

This is best done at Unit Test level:

1. Install rspec-rails gem:

Gemfile:

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5'
end
```

run `rails g rspec:install`

2. Create the following spec:

spec/models/comment_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Comment, type: :model do
  let(:post) { Post.create(title: 'title', author: 'author', body: 'body', published_at: DateTime.now) }

  it 'is destroyed when its associated Post is destroyed' do
    post.comments.create(title: 'title', author: 'author', body: 'body', published_at: DateTime.now)
    expect { post.destroy }.to change{ Comment.count }.by(-1)
  end
end
```

There are a few ways to approach that spec, but that's a debate for another time - this is one way to do it.

To make this test pass (run `rspec` to run this test), add a 'dependent destroy' declaration to your `Post` model:

app/models/post.rb:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  validates :author, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true
  validates :published_at, presence: true
end
```

That will make your test pass!

As a final tip, put `--format documentation` in your `.rspec` file to make rspec print passing tests (a personal preference of mine).

I would then build a Rake Task called 'tests' that runs both your RSpec specs and your Cucumber specs, but that's not for this thread.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I'm blind. I'll fix that.